# Notation and shorthand of cobordism G=O, SO, U

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, geometric-topology, cobordism

This is really a basic question:

From Wikipedia:
["The basic examples are G = O for unoriented cobordism, G = SO for oriented cobordism, and G = U for complex cobordism using stably complex manifolds."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism)

> Question: I just wonder what it the meaning of abbreviation/shorthand **O/SO/U** which implies **unoriented/oriented/complex** cobordism?

I suppose O has something to do with **oriented**, and U is related to a complex ; what is S? What is O and U really?

Comment: Orthogonal / Special orthogonal / unitary (as in [Lie group names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#Examples_with_n_dimensions)).

Comment: Thanks, if this is correct, yours is qualified as an answer. :-)

Comment: @ Grigory M: Can you explain why Orthogonal / Special orthogonal / unitary relates to or fully captures all cases of unoriented/oriented/complex cobordism? Excuse me.